# Matlab - euclidean distance of specific elements between two vectors

Tags: matlab, indexing, distance

I'm trying to find the coordinates/index that has the minimum distance of an element in a 2d array to another same element 2d array. I have a binary image from my edge detection problem and a ground truth image. For example, I have A as my binary image  and B as the ground truth image:

```
A = [0 255 255 255;255 255 255 255;255 255 255 255;255 255 255 255 ]

B = [255 255 255 255;255 255 255 255; 255 255 0 255; 255 255 0 0]
```

0 is black and 255 is white. My algorithm goes like this:

```
 for n=1:maxindex
if(A(n)==0&&B(n)==0)
distance(n) = 0;

elseif(A(n)==0&&B(n)==255)
for m=1: maxindex
     if(B(m)==0&&m~=n)
        translate index to subscripts
        compute euclidean distance
        store value in temporary vector
    end
 end
find minimum in temporary vector
distance(n) = minimum found
```

end
end

The algorithm really takes a long time for large images, since it's exhaustive when there's a mismatch. Is there a function in Matlab that would make this faster?

Comment: Did you google it before? The first result was [`pdist`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) which can be set to `euclidean` distance.

Comment: I tried googling and knnsearch was the one appearing and others. Maybe I didn't worded it right. Thanks for the links. Pdist is for one matrix. I'll try to understand on how I can do it with two.